# How to use NPGSQL.GetBytes() function

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

In my Postgres database, I have a bytea column. In my program, I can insert to this column, however, when I go to retrieve that data I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No row is available'

I can access the other column in that record but when I try either of these methods:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
bytes = (byte[])dr[3];


byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
dr.GetBytes(3, 0, bytes, 0, 16);
```

The error gets thrown. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added the query

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM as_users WHERE name = @name";

        if (OpenConnection())
        {
            NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, Connection);
            npgsqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", username);
            npgsqlCommand.Prepare();
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = npgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //Doesnt work
                byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
                dr.GetBytes(3, 0, bytes, 0, 16);

                //Does work
                string name = dr.GetString(1);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: If you're sure that the data is inserted, the problem is with the query, not with this code.

Comment: @jeroenh then why can I read other columns from the same record if the query doesn't work?

Comment: I can only guess if you don't provide a [minimal but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem

Comment: @jeroenh Ive completed the example, see the edits

Comment: How are you reading the other columns of that record? Also, better to explicitly name columns instead of using `select *`.

Comment: string name = dr.GetString(1);

Comment: Try query without WHERE.  The error is due to no rows being returned.  So removing the where will give indication if there is data in the database table.  You could be connecting to a database with no data or the database with no table as_users.

Comment: @jdweng Adam claims (but does not prove with code) that there is data in the table, as he can query other columns inside that same code block.

Comment: I have appended a screenshot from my editor that shows the 2nd column being stored in i and .GetBytes() crashing the program. However, I'm starting to believe this is a database issue more than a NPGSQL issue.

Comment: I can confirm this was a database issue.  I assume there was an issue with the bytea column hence why the other columns were accessible. Dropping and recreating the table solved the solution. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues explained were caused by an error within the database, not the NPGSQL function. Dropping and recreating the table solved the issue. Below is what I believe is an acceptable way to access data from a bytea column.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
dr.GetBytes(3, 0, bytes, 0, 16);
```

Comment: Can you please accept this as the answer to your own question?